# knockout Bind checkboxlist checked items to another checkboxlist

Tags: knockout.js

using knockout.js
I have a checkbox list and when i checked item it will add to another checkbox list item. I mean all checked items from list to another checkbox. Secondly when I uncheck the second list item it will remove form current and uncheck from parent.

[jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/90/](http://jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/90/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="timetable">
    <ul class="calendar-short select-time" data-bind="template: { foreach: results }, style: { display: results().length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }">       
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" data-bind="value: id, checked: $parent.selectedChoices, attr: { id: 'timetable_' + id }">
            <label class="checkbox" data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'for': 'timetable_' + id }"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="timetable">
    <ul class="calendar-short select-time" data-bind="template: { foreach: results1 }, style: { display: results().length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }">       
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" data-bind="value: id, checked: $parent.selectedChoices, attr: { id: 'timetable_' + id }">
            <label class="checkbox" data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'for': 'timetable_' + id }"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var anil = {
    results: ko.observableArray([{
        'id': 1,
            'name': 'anil'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
            'name': 'akash'
    }]),
    selectedChoices: ko.observableArray([]),
    results1:ko.observableArray([])
}
anil.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {            
            anil.results1 = ko.observableArray(anil.selectedChoices());        
            return anil.results1();
        });   

ko.applyBindings(anil);
```

Comment: can you try to elaborate little bit . i am not really sure what you are trying to achieve .

Comment: @Pawan Bali - You have to add code that you've tried so far. Linking jsfiddle without code samples are not allowed here. Please read SO help page for more details http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/89/ here is the thing which i want to implement but  where is the problem in my code http://jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/90/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

you need to query the `results` based on the selected checkboxes and push `object` to `results2` array for binding name & id respectively to view.

**viewModel :**

```
var anil = {
    results: ko.observableArray([{
        'id': 1,
            'name': 'anil'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
            'name': 'akash'
    }]),
    selectedChoices: ko.observableArray([]),
    results1:ko.observableArray([])
}

anil.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
  anil.results1([]);
   ko.utils.arrayForEach(anil.selectedChoices(), function (item1) {
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(anil.results(), function (item2) {
        if (item2.id == item1) {
            anil.results1.push(item2);
        }
      });
   });
}); 

ko.applyBindings(anil);
```

**View:**.

```
<div id="timetable">
    <ul class="calendar-short select-time" data-bind="template: { foreach: results1 }, style: { display: results().length > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }">       
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedChoices, attr: { id: 'timetable_' + $data }"/>
            <label class="checkbox" data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'for': 'timetable_' + $data }"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: selectedChoicesDelimited"></div>
```

working sample fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/105/)

Comment: hi super cool, your code works thanks but the checkbox shows only text result not other thing. like anil and akash.